# Why does Eclipse's indexer recognize some classes, but not others?

Tags: c++, eclipse, parsing, indexing, mbed

I setup Eclipse C++ - Version: Neon Release (4.6.0) - Build id: 20160613-1800 - with the GNU gcc ARM Embedded Toolchain (not gcc4mbed). The toolchain works great, but I ran into an issue involving (I think) Eclipse's indexer on my latest project.

My problem should be clear if I give the steps to reproduce my issue:

1. Create some class and #include "mbed.h"
2. Declare some member variable of type DigitalOut. Notice that Eclipse recognizes this just fine because the text turns bold, and code completion works fine when interacting with the variable.
3. Declare another member variable of type PwmOut. Notice that Eclipse does NOT recognize this, the text does not turn bold, and code completion doesn't work because Eclipse doesn't know what a PwmOut is. Eclipse says:

> Errors (1 item)
>
> Type 'PwmOut' could not be resolved.  -  main.cpp  -  Semantic Error

4. Build project completes successfully, compiler throws no errors, even though Eclipse still does not recognize PwmOut. Binary runs correctly on my LPC1768.

How is it possible that Eclipse can recognize DigitalOut but not PwmOut? Both are listed in the same code block inside mbed.h--and DigitalOut.h is in the same directory as PwmOut.h.

If it helps, [here is an example project](http://www.filedropper.com/testmbedprojectgccarmlpc1768) I exported from developer.mbed.org that you can import into Eclipse C++ as an existing Makefile project.

I have tried adapting suggestions I found such as adding the directory with these headers in Project->Properties->C/C++ General->Paths and Symbols->Includes, rebuilding the index, and "Freshening" all files in the index. I just can't get Eclipse to recognize them.

EDIT: I'd like to add that if I click on the "Type 'PwmOut' could not be resolved" error message in the "Problems" window, Eclipse locks up for a few seconds, then crashes with a stack overflow.

Comment: One thing to check for is names defined in the makefile that are not defined in the code. Codan may think `PwmOut` is being left out because of conditional compilation.

Comment: @user4581301 thank you for the suggestion. Could you clarify what you mean? Here is a gist of the Makefile that comes with the projects when you export them from developer.mbed.org https://gist.github.com/yankee14/c73325c1ab035c167bc2b3c3117dfe09

Comment: Sorry, but I don't download anonymous stuff off the Internet. What you're looking for is uses of the gcc compiler option `-D` in the compiler rules in the makefile. These are often used to turn functionality on or off by instructing the compiler to not compile regions of code. For example, `#ifdef DEBUG <EOL> std::cerr << "Debug Message\n" #endif`.  "Debug Message" will be printed if DEBUG has been defined either with `#define DEBUG` above it in the code or `-D DEBUG ` on the compiler command line. Note this is only a common solution to this problem. It may not be your solution.

Comment: I do see a lot of -Doptions in the makefile on line 56 of that link I gave you. I see one that says -DDEVICE_PWMOUT=1.

I asked my instructor about this, he suggested I try adding:

#define DEVICE_PWMOUT 1 to the line just above the #include "mbed.h" This completely solves my problem, Eclipse now recognizes PwmOut class. I don't understand why, though...

By the way, I wasn't asking you to download anything. A gist is just like a pastebin of the Makefile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sorry to say that my solution probably isn't very generalizable or helpful to other people's Eclipse C++ issues.

## Solution:

1. In your developer.mbed.org exported project folder, find the file "device.h" located in the mbed subdirectory at

   ```
   ./mbed/TARGET_LPC1768/TARGET_NXP/TARGET_LPC176X/TARGET_MBED_LPC1768/device.h
   ```

Mine was more or less empty.

2. Replace this device.h with the [one located at the mbed official repo](https://developer.mbed.org/users/mbed_official/code/mbed-src/file/a11c0372f0ba/targets/hal/TARGET_NXP/TARGET_LPC176X/TARGET_MBED_LPC1768/device.h) for the LPC1768.

Notice this device.h has a bit more detail in it.

3. Rebuild Eclipse's index. Eclipse should now be happy.

## **My interpretation of why this fixes Eclipse's problem:**

When you export a project from developer.mbed.org, it gives you a zip with all your sources, as well as an "./mbed" directory that contains the header files and objects for the specific microcontroller with which you're working.

Most of NXP/ARM's controllers should have some variation of a DigitalOut or DigitalIn class, since that kind of functionality is very basic and common to a controller. However, this particular chip (the LPC1768) has an independent module onboard to handle pulse width modulation. This module might not be found on all of NXP/ARM's chips, so you can think of this as a special case we need to take care of when setting up a workspace environment in an IDE such as Eclipse.

Particularly, the mbed exported project contains a header located (for me) at

```
./mbed/TARGET_LPC1768/TARGET_NXP/TARGET_LPC176X/TARGET_MBED_LPC1768/device.h
```

This device header *should* define preprocessor directives specific to the device you're programming. Mine was empty, [but the one at the official repo for the LPC1768](https://developer.mbed.org/users/mbed_official/code/mbed-src/file/a11c0372f0ba/targets/hal/TARGET_NXP/TARGET_LPC176X/TARGET_MBED_LPC1768/device.h) has a lot of #defines in it for this controller. As long as the DEVICE_PWMOUT directive in device.h is defined to be equal to 1 (and it is), Eclipse will know that it is supposed to recognize the PwmOut class.

Comment: device.h file was deprecated, therefore it is now almost empty, and all the target info is in the targets.json file -> as you have noticed, macros are defined via -D that contains all those DEVICE_ definitions.

You can raise this as an improvement in mbed-os github repository, that we should generate header file with device configuration (there's mbed config  but thats for something else).

Comment: @c0170 Thank you for the suggestion, I submitted the improvement https://github.com/ARMmbed/mbed-os/issues/2738

Comment: The fix in mbed (which I gather generates a suitable header file when running the `eclipse_gcc_arm` exporter) does not work for mDot projects because "MTS_MDOT_F411RE not supported by eclipse_gcc_arm". We're still stuck with non-stop indexer issues.